# Receiving a Render OverFlow Error in Flutter Application for Row

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-web

I'm having a render overflow error where text goes off the screen..I'm new to flutter and I can't for the life of me figure out how to fix it. Any pointers on how I could resolve it? I've tried a bunch of different things based on other questions but for whatever reason none of them worked.

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/widgets.dart';
import 'package:save_extra_money/shared/globals/ProjectColors.dart';

import '../../model/Transaction.dart';

class DetailRow extends StatelessWidget {
  final String fieldName;
  final String text;
  final Color textColor;

  const DetailRow({
    Key? key,
    required this.text,
    required this.fieldName,
    this.textColor = ProjectColors.normalText,
  }) : super(key: key);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      color: Colors.white,
      padding: EdgeInsets.all(5),
      child: Row(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.start,
        children: [
          Container(
            alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
            color: Colors.white,
            child: Container(
              child: Flexible(
                child: Column(
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      fieldName,
                      style: TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      text,
                      overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      style: TextStyle(fontSize: 30,
                      color: textColor),
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Main problem here is that child width is larger than its parents beacuse *Container* widget child get unbounded width from *Row* widget

you can write your code after *return* like this:

```
Container(
        color: Colors.white,
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(5),
        child: IntrinsicHeight(
          child: Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Flexible(
                child: Container(
                  alignment: Alignment.topLeft,
                  color: Colors.white,
                  child: Column(
                    crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                    children: <Widget>[
                      Text(
                        fieldName,
                        style: const TextStyle(color: Colors.black54),
                      ),
                      Text(
                        text,
                        style: const TextStyle(fontSize: 30, color: textColor),
                        overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
                      ),
                    ],
                  ),
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

Also, Text widget has property maxLines, so you can also set the exact number of lines.

IntrinsicHeight is a widget that sizes its child to the child's intrinsic height.

https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/IntrinsicHeight-class.html

Answer (score 1):

Widget overflow is a common issue to face when you first start with Flutter. Usually, you can solve it in more than one way.

In your case, you are giving unbounded width to the `Text` widget. your Widget tree is as follows:
`Container -> Row -> Container -> Column -> text`

And because you are wrapping a `Container` with a `Row` widget, that gives unbounded width to the child of the `Container`. Therefore, your text will keep expanding horizontally so you can fix this by either giving the `Container` a static width or by wrapping it with the `Expanded` or `Flexible` widget.

To understand more about how Expanded and Flexible works I suggest you to read [Expanded vs Flexible](https://medium.com/@apmntechdev/flutter-expanded-and-flex-cfd4e9f1e069)